# Problems installing ASUS USB-AC54 driver to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, compiling, asus

I have recently bought an ASUS USB-AC54 wifi adapter for my Linux PC with Ubuntu 18.04 operating system. The package states that the adapter has Linux support, but there is no driver for Linux. The closest available driver is for USB-54_B1, which I downloaded and tried to install.

Briefly

1. download from https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-AC54-B1/HelpDesk_Download/
2. extract
3. change working directory `cd Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959`
4. install with `bash install.sh`

Here is the last 25% of the log as the start includes only some warnings but no errors. Any help is welcome! ASUS IT support was not very helpful and just me to ask here...

Errors

```
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   set_fs(get_ds());
          ^~~~~~
          get_da
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2228:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
    set_fs(get_ds());
           ^~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2263:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
    set_fs(get_ds());
           ^~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:273: recipe for target '/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
Makefile:1757: recipe for target '/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/jimm/Downloads/Linux/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-52-generic'
Makefile:1986: recipe for target 'modules' failed
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b05:1841 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1c00 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question andd add output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 for the input. I added the output of lsusb.

Comment: The driver from ASUS site won't work with new Ubuntu releases. You need to find a patched driver, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1063474/167850

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. Tried that and rebooted. No effect. Tried also to reinstall the Asus driver after that, but had the same error message. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Yes it is disabled.

Comment: Did the other driver compile without errors?